# Upload new item (node gallery) link not showing with a user of different permission - Drupal 7

Tags: users, media

I created a new content type named "Home" which is connected to node gallery. I created a new role named "Home only" and gave permission. When I logged in as a user with role of Home only, I am not able to get the "Upload new item" link. Did I miss any permission. Please give me a solution.

I gave all "Home" Node level permission, File Entity permission, Filter permission,View the administration theme permission, Use the administration pages and help permission.

Please note: I am getting the "Upload new item" link when I logged as administrator. Also plupload is using for the bulk upload.

[image: Please see the below image where I am getting Upload new item link when i logged as an administrator]
When I logged as "Home only" level user, I getting all the links as in the above image except "Upload new items"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it worked. Previously its was beta version of node gallery. Now I changed it into Node gallery-7.x-1.0. In the permission tab i had checked "Node Gallery API". In the case of beta version of node gallery these was not showing.